# error NU1010: The PackageReference items MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets do not have corresponding PackageVersion

Tags: web, targets-r-package

Hope you can help, I’m having this error at moment I run dotnet build,  I check the version of  MSbuild and I have   version 15  but no sure   what fileI need to update I’m new on this world of dev.

Myfile.Website.csproj : error NU1010: The PackageReference items MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets do not have corresponding PackageVersion.

Any idea   how to solve the issue I have VS 2022

checked the target file
setup Directory.package.props file